# 'Number of Faculty Members' not Available in the College Scorecard Dataset

Tags: data-request, collegescorecard

The College Scorecard has data on the 'Average faculty salary' and 'Proportion of faculty that is full-time', but it does not report any data on total number of faculty. Does anyone have any suggestions where I can find these data (or something similar)?

I think this would be a really valuable variable to include in the College Scorecard, considering that the student to faculty ratio is a standard measure of college quality.

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, 1.5M faculty.

> About 3.9 million people were employed in colleges and universities in the fall of 2013, **including 1.5 million faculty**, 0.4 million graduate assistants, and 2.0 million other staff. About 64 percent of the staff worked full time and 36 percent worked part time. About 2.1 million, or 54 percent, of all staff were female (see Digest of Education Statistics, 2014, table 314.30).

https://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/mobile/TeachersFacultyAndStaff_DGI_College_Staff.aspx

If you need granular stats by university, specifically:

> Full-time instructional staff by academic rank, faculty and tenure status

https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/InstitutionByName.aspx